# How to make a table row highlight if the checkbox is checked (on button click)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-table

I am creating a Jquery Mobile page which includes a table. The table will display users. Table rows include checkboxes in the first cell, followed by the users information. At the bottom of the table there is a button (Edit). When this button is clicked I want the rows which have their check boxes ticked to be highlighted and the cells in the row editable.

I want to highlight/make editable rows on the click of the edit button, when

- a) the rows checkbox is ticked.

The table has been created using a JavaScript loop (function is loaded on page load).

```
var UsersHTML = "<table class='full_width_table info_table_style ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive'>" +
                        "<thead>" +
                           "<tr class='ui-bar-b schedule_row'>" +
                             "<th></th>" +
                             "<th>UserID</th>" +
                             "<th>First Name</th>" +
                             "<th>Surname</th>" +
                             "<th>Home Location</th>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                         "</thead>" +
                         "<tbody>";



for (s = 0; s < 15; s++) {
    //contenteditable='true'
    UsersHTML += "<tr class='schedule_row'>" +
         "<td class='user_check_cell'>" +"<input type='checkbox'>" + "</td>" +
         "<td> " + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + + "</td>" +
         "<td align='right'";


    UsersHTML += "</td></tr>";
}

UsersHTML += "</tbody></table>";

$("#usersContent").html(UsersHTML);
```

I have used a div to display the table on the page:

```
<div id="usersContent">
        </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation.

```
$('#userContent').on('click', '.user_check_cell input[type=checkbox]', function () {
  var $input = $(this);
  $input.closest('tr').toggleClass('highlighted', $input.prop('checked'));
});
```

This adds the event listener to `#userContent` and listens for events on that and if the element that triggered that click event matches the selector in `on` it goes though with the event.

The `toggleClass` just adds the class "highlighted" when the input that was clicked is checked.

Comment: Nice, clean solution, +1. My only amendment would be to use $(this).is(":checked") as your switch parameter on toggleClass, seeing as jQuery is available to obfuscate any browser peculiarities.

Comment: I switched it to `.prop('checked')` but I think just `this.checked` would be OK nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div id="usersContent">
        </div>
```

**js:**

```
var UsersHTML = "<table class='full_width_table info_table_style ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive'>" +
                        "<thead>" +
                           "<tr class='ui-bar-b schedule_row'>" +
                             "<th></th>" +
                             "<th>UserID</th>" +
                             "<th>First Name</th>" +
                             "<th>Surname</th>" +
                             "<th>Home Location</th>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                         "</thead>" +
                         "<tbody>";



for (s = 0; s < 15; s++) {
    //contenteditable='true'
    UsersHTML += "<tr class='schedule_row' id='testTr_"+s+"'>" +
         "<td class='user_check_cell'>" +"<input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+s+"' specId='"+s+"' class='hightlight' onclick='changeHight(this);'>" + "</td>" +
         "<td> " + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + + "</td>" +
         "<td align='right'";


    UsersHTML += "</td></tr>";
}

UsersHTML += "</tbody></table>";

$("#usersContent").html(UsersHTML);



window.changeHight = function(obj){
    var specTr = $(obj).attr("specId");
    if($(obj).prop("checked"))
      $("#testTr_"+specTr).addClass("highlight");
    else
      $("#testTr_"+specTr).removeClass("highlight");
}
```

**css:**

```
.highlight{
    background: green;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zquDj/13/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat :), but I need to make it so that the rows are highlighted when the edit button is clicked. So the user will click/tick the checkboxes on the rows they want to edit, then when they have finished selecting they will click the edit button - this will then highlight the selected rows. Also how can I make the rows editable at the same time as highlighting them? Thanks for your help/time, much appreciated! :)

Comment: So there is a button when clicked then hightlight TR's with checked checkbox?

Comment: Thanks very much for the updated code! How can I make it so that the highlighted row also becomes editable?

Comment: When clicking the "Edit" button, the highlighted rows will become editable, i.e the content in highlighted rows becomes editable in textboxes?

Comment: Can you make another question about this one? Cause this one has title "How to make a table row highlight if the checkbox is checked (on button click)?"

Answer (score 0):

First, I would encourage you to look into some sort of framework to make this easier.  jsRender, Knockout.js and Angular.js would all make this cleaner and easier.

Without going down any of those roads, I would do something like this...

Add a couple classes to help us out....

```
.display input {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
}

.hightlight {
    background-color: #ffffbb;
}
```

If you want to make the cells editable, you need to wrap them in an input. Disable the input and remove the border when in "display mode"...

```
$('#userTable').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.removeClass('display');
    row.addClass('hightlight');
    row.find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
})
```

I also changed your code a bit to add an array of users and add the user data to the table...

for (

```
s = 0; s < 15; s++) {
    //contenteditable='true'
    UsersHTML += "<tr class='schedule_row display'>" +
         "<td class='user_check_cell'>" +"<input type='checkbox'>" + "</td>" +
         "<td> " + s + "</td>" +
          "<td><input disabled='disabled' value='" + users[s].firstName + "'></input></td>" +
          "<td>" + users[s].lastName + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + users[s].location + "</td>";


    UsersHTML += "</tr>";
}
```

Working fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/gRFD8/1/

Comment: Thanks for the solution :). This works great, however I'm not sure how to make this happen on the click of a button - i.e the rows are highlighted when the edit button is clicked. So the user will click/tick the checkboxes on the rows they want to edit, then when they have finished selecting they will click the edit button - this will then highlight/expose textboxes on the selected rows. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Oh yeah. Totally doable. Check this out... http://jsfiddle.net/gRFD8/2/  That's closer to what you're looking for.